# Magento giving error on searching product

Tags: php, magento

The problem is in catalog search when I type any product in search box on the homepage called "Search entire store".It gives me "There has been an error processing your request" with the following error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:60:"Category must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Category.";i:1;s:4744:"#0 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer.php(187): Mage::throwException('Category must b...')

1.C:\wamp\www\shop\app\design\frontend\evoque\default\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml(111): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer->setCurrentCategory(NULL)

2 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\wamp\www\sho...')

3 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template-fetchView('frontend\evoque...')

4 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

5 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

6 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

7 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('toolbar', true)

8 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php(204): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('toolbar')

9 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\design\frontend\evoque\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml(50): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->getToolbarHtml()

10 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\wamp\www\sho...')

11 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template-
>fetchView('frontend\evoque...')

12 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

13 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

14 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

15 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('search_result_l...', true)

16 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Block\Result.php(161): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('search_result_l...')

17 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalogsearch\result.phtml(42): Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result->getProductListHtml()

18 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\wamp\www\sho...')

19 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\base\d...')

20 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

21 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

22 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\local\Etheme\Evoqueconfig\Block\Core\Text\List.php(23): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

23 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Etheme_Evoqueconfig_Block_Core_Text_List->_toHtml()

24 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

25 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)

26 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\design\frontend\evoque\default\template\page\3columns.phtml(59): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')

27 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\wamp\www\sho...')

28 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\evoque...')

29 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

30 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

31 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

32 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()

33 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\controllers\ResultController.php(80): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()

34 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController->indexAction()

35 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')

36 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

37 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

38 C:\wamp\www\shop\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

39 C:\wamp\www\shop\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

40 {main}";s:3:"url";s:42:"/shop/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=sk";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/shop/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, Ivan Stein

Comment: Please check the error log in the system.log file under the root/var/log folder

Answer (score -1):

Something is getting mixed up somewhere. I'd say either a modification someone made that the theme isn't expecting, a certain store or category configuration via the Magento Admin, or a bug in the evoque theme.

Evoque is a premium theme and you can [get support from the authors here](http://etheme.ticksy.com/?envato_item_id=6097979).

We can see from the error report that the point of failure is line 111 of file `C:\wamp\www\shop\app\design\frontend\evoque\default\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml`

To fix this glitch you should examine that file and either test for a null category before executing line 111 or do some analysis to work out why the category is NULL for your particular use-case.

Feel free to paste, say, lines 101 to 121 of `toolbar.phtml` here and you may get a solution (involving the creation of a custom sub-theme with a more robust `toolbar.phtml`) but I recommend raising a ticket at the [official theme support site](http://etheme.ticksy.com/?envato_item_id=6097979).